# Post data to current page for validation and pass post data onto second page for processing

Tags: php, workflow

I have a situation where I have a form on multiple pages that all post their data to a "thank you" page with code that emails the data to me.

**Validation failure**
I need to do php validation on the page the form is on so that if one of the required fields isn't filled in, I can reload the page with the form fields pre-populated with the info the user input.

**Validation success**
If the validation passes I then need to send the data to the "thank you" page to be emailed to me

I have no idea if this is possible. If there's a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do, suggestions are welcome.

**Better explanation?**

- domain.com/page1 - form on page
- domain.com/page2 - form on page
- domain.com/page3 - form on page
- domain.com/page4 - form on page

All forms currently post to domain.com/thank-you where data is sent via email using phpmailer

PHP validation must happen on pages with forms. Data must then be sent to domain.com/thank-you so that it can be sent via email.

Comment: '*If there's a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do*' - Better way implies you have showed us your current attempt at this, where is your current attempt?

Comment: I was implying that if my thought process on what I've written above is dumb and I should do it another way, then the suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: please post your code here

Comment: @sree is my explanation not clear enough?

Comment: why cant you keep your validation code and email sending code in one place, after the email is sent, you can redirect your pages to thank-you page.

Comment: I could put the validation code on the thank-you.php page where the email code is, but how do I send the post data back to the page it was sent from if the validation fails. And how will I know which page to send the data to since there are multiple different pages with the form on?

Comment: Instead of the above, keep your validation code and email code in the respective form pages, if everything is fine and email is sent, redirect to thank-you page. if anything fails, it will stay in the same form page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173612/discussion-between-venomrush-and-sree).